# Using GlassMapper Models in View Rendering

Tags: glass-mapper

**Sitecore 9.3**

I have a `view rendering` where I was previously using the `RenderingModel` in the view,

([image])

but have switched to using the `GlassMapper classes` instead

([image]).

This works great unless the component's data source is an unpublished item. If this happens, on the published page, I get a null exception error.

My view rendering item currently has nothing for the Model.

[image]

Comment: can you try to add Namespaces.NameofClass,Namespaces? in your case : bc.Templates.Project.AlphaBetaCappa.ContentTypes.Image,bc.Templates.Project.AlphaBetaCappa

Comment: @VladIobagiu I didn't mention it in my question, but I did try that, yes. I get the same error, "could not locate type". I tried, "Abc.Templates.Project.AlphaBetaCappa.ContentTypes.Image,Abc.Templates.Project.AlphaBetaCappa.ContentTypes" and I also tried, "Abc.Templates.Project.AlphaBetaCappa.ContentTypes.Image,Abc.Templates.Project.AlphaBetaCappa"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your issue is similar to the one specified on the glass mapper issue list https://github.com/mikeedwards83/Glass.Mapper/issues/163. The workaround for the error is replacing the `GetViewRenderer` pipeline action:

```
public class GetViewRendererWithItemValidation : GetViewRenderer
    {        
        protected override Renderer GetRenderer(Rendering rendering, GetRendererArgs args)
        {           
            var viewRenderer = base.GetRenderer(rendering, args) as ViewRenderer;
            if (viewRenderer == null)
                return null;

            // Ignore item check when in page editor
            // Also this will break if the item for the datasource has been deleted without removing the link.
            if (Context.PageMode.IsPageEditor || Context.PageMode.IsPageEditorEditing)
                return viewRenderer;

            // Override renderer to null when there is an unpublished item refererenced by underlying view
            return viewRenderer.Rendering.Item != null && viewRenderer.Rendering.RenderingItem.InnerItem != null
                ? viewRenderer
                : null;
        }
    }
```

Add the above as a new class in your project and activate the existing glass mapper config file z.Glass.Mapper.Sc.ViewRender.config.exclude

Also if you are using glass mapper version 4 or higher you can leave the model field blank and Glass should resolve the model based on the declaration in the view rendering's cshtml file.

Comment: I am using 5.8.177 and, when I leave the model field blank, it's giving me that error if the datasource isn't published. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I tried your suggested solution and it made no difference for me. It's possible I don't know how to properly implement? I just basically pasted the code into a new class file. Had to add some using statements.

Comment: Can you try and activate the existing glass mapper config file z.Glass.Mapper.Sc.ViewRender.config.exclude? It contains a patch for the GetViewRenderer pipeline.

Comment: That did the trick. I also suggested that as an edit to your solution to make it complete. Thank you!

Comment: FYI, this partially resolved the issue. I still get the error when I preview a page with an unpublishable item, but on the published page, no error occurs.